# Можно ли создать простую визуализацию программы на Java?

Tags: java, интерфейс, визуализация

Есть поле 100 х 100, по нему бегают мышки и ищут кустики разноцветные. Когда мышка находит кустик первая - она выигрывает и становится цвета кустика.
Программа написана. Вопрос: можно ли это визуализировать? Если да, то каким образом? В каком направлении копать?

Comment: java fx вам в помощь

Comment: Нужно научится рисовать на экран спрайты (картинки) с мышью и кустиком (нарисованными в любом графическом редакторе) посредством Graphics2D, изображение поля можно опять же нарисовать (сгенерировать) посредством Graphics2D во вне экранное изображение, ну а дальше в цикле обновлять состояние модели, затем рисовать кадр сперва скопировав изображение поля на экран, затем копируя картинки кустов и мышей по разным координатам. Ну или использовать LibGDX какой нибудь, там наверняка будет тот же самый принцип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создание GUI через Swing, либо JavaJX.
2. Через фреймворки для разработки игровых \ мультимедия приложений, например LibGDX. 
   Второе более удобно, так как даёт возможность сразу запустить ту же самую игру на Android, помимо Desktop платформ.

Comment: а с чем проще разобраться будет?:)

Comment: Если вам нужен простой интерфейс: кнопочки, поля ввода текста, чекбоксы, радио кнопки и т.п. Будет проще использовать Swing.
Если вам нужна игра, где нет\почти нет подобных элементов, а нужно манипулировать изображениями, реагировать на нажатия клавиш, например, нажал стрелку влево, картинка двигается, добавить музыку\звуки, тогда лучше LibGDX.

Answer (score 1):

Если запускать будете на десктопе, и не стоит задача написания полноценного игрового приложения, стоит попробовать Swing.
Возможно это будет полезно:
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/basics/